# Passing direction as a variable to jquery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass direction variable to jquery animate and the animation doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">Box</div>
```

**JS**

```
var direction = 'left';
$('.box').animate({direction : '100'},500);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyrXH/)

Comment: thanks gallery guy since i was doing a simple animate i didn't want to use jquery ui, so had to accept the answer by archer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a object to pass in that encapsulates all the animate options you require, and you can add to them using variables as names...

http://jsfiddle.net/FyrXH/

```
var direction = 'left';
var options = {};
options[direction] = 100;
$('.box').animate(options, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable as an object's property that way, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) for setting the property and then pass the object to the function:

```
var o = {};
o[direction] = 100;
$('.box').animate(o, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QmmSu/

Answer (score 0):

`direction` in the second line is the property name itself, it does not get substituted for a variable of the same name.

What you can do, is pass the *whole* object as a variable:

```
var direction = {left : '100'};
$('.box').animate(direction,500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FyrXH/

Comment: I guess that the main point to use variable `direction` is to be able to dynamically change direction of animation, to let's say, `right`. Your solution is hard-coded `left`-only.